# Get the height of a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I am trying to make a navigation, that sets the "active" class to links whenever it scrolls a specified ammount of pixels. But there is a div on the page, that get's its size based on user interaction.

This is the code for setting the active class.

```
$(function() {
//caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".active");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >=760) {
        header.removeClass('active').addClass("active1");
    } 
    else { header.removeClass('active1').addClass('active');}
});

    var header1 = $("#work");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 759  && scroll < 780) {
        header1.removeClass('#work').addClass("active");
    } else {
        header1.removeClass("active").addClass('#work');
    }
});

var header2 = $("#about");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 779 && scroll < 1450) {
        header2.removeClass('#about').addClass("active");
    } else {
        header2.removeClass("active").addClass('#about');
    }
});

var header3 = $("#contact");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 1449) {
        header3.removeClass('#contact').addClass("active");
    } else {
        header3.removeClass("active").addClass('#contact');
    }
});
});
```

How do I get the height of a div which has it's class set as auto, and then apply it in the code above ?

EDIT: I tried the `$('#ID').height();` but it gets the height when the website is loaded, and it doesn't work after any user interacts with the div.

Comment: could you create a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

In basically get the height of the DIV

```
$('#ID').height();
```

it returns height.

Comment: But how do I apply it on my current code.
Do I set a variable as `#('#ID').height();` , and then wherever i have pixels, i do for example `759 + variable` ?

Comment: add the id to the div tag in html and call where the height is required

Comment: I'm pretty new to jquery, so sorry if I'm making some obvious mistake.
There is the div "#two", which has child divs that expand when clicked. So I need the height of the #two div with its children divs expanded. I am making a variable `twoHeight = $('#two').height();` . And then in the code above, I add it like this: `if (scroll >= 759 + twoHeight  && scroll < 780 + twoHeight`

Comment: yes if you want #two div hight means just add var twoHeight = $('#two').height(); it will returns height and use it wherever it requires

Comment: because you called function in document,ready so it one time process.so whenever the div is clicked we called that function to get height

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

### Sample [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/YxRqp/361/)

```
if($("#ID").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight())
```

If you create a fiddle possibly can do the same for you

Hope this helps, Thank you